# Please help me to understand a html5 game's code

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a trouble to understand this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F2Dc-JlwgN4 .

```
<canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
ctx.font = '30px Arial';
var height = 500;
var width = 500;
var message = "bouncing";
var player = {
    x:50,
    speedX:30,
    y: 40,
    speedY: 5,
    name: "P",
};
function getDistanceBetweenEntity(entity1, entity2){
    var vx = entity1.x - entity2.x;
    var vy = entity1.y - entity2.y;
    return Math.sqrt (vx*vx+vy*vy);
}

function testCollisionEntity(entity1, entity2){
    var distance = getDistanceBetweenEntity(entity1, entity2);
    return distance < 30;
}

var enemyList = {};
enemey("E1", 150, 350, 10, 15, "E1");
enemey("E2", 250, 350, 10, -15, "E2");

function enemey(id,x,y,speedX,speedY, name) {
var enemy2 = {
    x: x,
    speedX:speedX,
    y: y,
    speedY: speedY,
    name: name,
    id:id,
};
    enemyList[id] = enemy2;
}
setInterval(update,40);
function updateEntity(something){
    something.x += something.speedX;
    something.y += something.speedY;
    ctx.fillText(something.name, something.x, something.y);

    if (something.x < 0 || something.x > width) {
        console.log(message);
        something.speedX =- something.speedX;
    }
    if (something.y < 0 || something.y > height) {
        console.log(message);
        something.speedY =- something.speedY;
    }

};
function update () {
ctx.clearRect(0,0,height,width);
for (var i in enemyList) {
    updateEntity(enemyList[i]);
    var isColliding = testCollisionEntity(player, enemyList[i]);
    if (isColliding){
        console.log('colliding!')
    }
}
    updateEntity(player);
}
</script>
```

Here is the jsfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/sinner019/0k9cnLce/

I do not understand how to this tow parameter entity1 and entity2 works. Would you please help me to understand.

Comment: This is simply Pythagoras, get the variation of distance between 2 points for x and y, and return the hypotenuse , what exactly do you not understand?

Comment: It is calculating the length of a [hypotenuse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotenuse) of a right triangle which is equivalent to calculating the distance between two points on a 2d cartesian coordinate system.

Comment: I cant understand which value passed into entity1 and entity2. Please take a look on full code http://jsfiddle.net/sinner019/0k9cnLce/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Pythagorean Theorem:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem

It's used to get the distance based on the difference in X and Y values.

vx is the difference in the x value  (or the X distance travelled)

vy is the difference in the y value

so it returns the Square Root of vx squared + vy squared thus solving the function:

distance^2 = x^2 + y^2

Comment: I need to understand how to entity1 and entity2 parameter works. Would you please explain it to me.

Comment: @Shuvo entity1 and entity2 are probably badly named variables - they look like they are objects referencing the position of those entities but they might as well be the whole entities themselves - somewhere in the code you call this function and pass those 2 entities and the function returns to you the distance of the hypotenuse based on those 2 entities position - you could do a console.log and find out yourself by inspecting them - other than that we can't help and shouldn't help you any further than that - you should read up on basics of Javascript first before attempting to build a game